Pymc-BART Index error
I am trying to follow an example notebook from here but I am running into some IndexErrors when executing the code.
Here's a Minimal working example:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pymc as pm
import pymc_bart as pmb
import pytensor.tensor as pt
from scipy.special import logit

# Read sample data
data_df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/juanitorduz/website_projects/master/data/retention_data.csv",
    parse_dates=["cohort", "period"],
)

# Processing data
eps = np.finfo(float).eps
train_data_red_df = data_df.query("cohort_age > 0").reset_index(drop=True)
train_obs_idx = train_data_red_df.index.to_numpy()
train_n_users = train_data_red_df["n_users"].to_numpy()
train_n_active_users = train_data_red_df["n_active_users"].to_numpy()
train_retention = train_data_red_df["retention"].to_numpy()
train_retention_logit = logit(train_retention + eps)
train_data_red_df["month"] = train_data_red_df["period"].dt.strftime("%m").astype(int)
features: list[str] = ["age", "cohort_age", "month"]
x_train = train_data_red_df[features]

# Model
with pm.Model(coords={"feature": features}) as model:
    # --- Data ---
    model.add_coord(name="obs", values=train_obs_idx, mutable=True)
    x = pm.MutableData(name="x", value=x_train, dims=("obs", "feature"))
    n_users = pm.MutableData(name="n_users", value=train_n_users, dims="obs")
    n_active_users = pm.MutableData(name="n_active_users", value=train_n_active_users, dims="obs")

    # --- Parametrization ---
    # The BART component models the image of the retention rate under the
    # logit transform so that the range is not constrained to [0, 1].
    mu = pmb.BART(
        name="mu",
        X=x,
        Y=train_retention_logit,
        dims="obs",
    )
    # We use the inverse logit transform to get the retention rate back into [0, 1].
    p = pm.Deterministic(name="p", var=pm.math.invlogit(mu), dims="obs")
    # We add a small epsilon to avoid numerical issues.
    p = pt.switch(pt.eq(p, 0), eps, p)
    p = pt.switch(pt.eq(p, 1), 1 - eps, p)

    # --- Likelihood ---
    n_active_users_estimated = pm.Binomial(
        name="n_active_users_estimated",
        n=n_users,
        p=p,
        observed=n_active_users,
        dims="obs",
    )

pm.model_to_graphviz(model=model)

# Fit model
with model:
    idata = pm.sample(draws=100, chains=1)
    posterior_predictive = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace=idata)

I have inspected the shapes of x_train and train_retention_logit passed to the BART method and they seem to have the right shapes, (1128,3) and (1128,), respectively.
Yet the sampling from the posterior returns an error that I do have not been able to trace back to its source:
IndexError: tuple index out of range
Apply node that caused the error: BART_rv{"(i00,i01),(i10),(),(),(),(i50)->(o00)"}(RNG(<Generator(PCG64) at 0x1721017E0>), [], x, [-1.609437 ... .51268651], 100, 0.95, 2.0, [])
Toposort index: 0
Inputs types: [RandomGeneratorType, TensorType(int64, shape=(0,)), TensorType(float64, shape=(None, None)), TensorType(float64, shape=(1128,)), TensorType(int8, shape=()), TensorType(float64, shape=()), TensorType(float32, shape=()), TensorType(float64, shape=(0,))]
Inputs shapes: ['No shapes', (0,), (1128, 3), (1128,), (), (), (), (0,)]
Inputs strides: ['No strides', (0,), (8, 9024), (8,), (), (), (), (0,)]
Inputs values: [Generator(PCG64) at 0x1721017E0, array([], dtype=int64), 'not shown', 'not shown', array(100, dtype=int8), array(0.95), array(2., dtype=float32), array([], dtype=float64)]
Outputs clients: [[output[1](BART_rv{"(i00,i01),(i10),(),(),(),(i50)->(o00)"}.0)], [Second(mu, [-3.09309984])]]

The versions of the relevant libraries are:
python 3.10.15
pymc 5.16.2
pymc-bart 0.7.0

in case it is related with differences in behaviour between package versions.

Have you raised this as a github issue?

Yes, just raised it. https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc-bart/issues/193

Thanks. You are doing git-repos a better place.

Apparently the issue is with the dims="obs" parameter passed to the BART method. If I comment that parameter it works fine, although I am not sure why, as the obs has the right size (1128,).
Maybe someone with more experience in pymc can elaborate and I can edit this answer accordingly.

(+1 for the debugging and sharing of ths)
